# Rod fell into overflow pipe of tub pop-up drain

Tags: bathtub

I have a Kohler pop-up tub drain and the lift rod fell off the crank piece of the overflow hood assembly.  What's the best approach to try and fish the rod, spring, etc., out?  Obviously, I don't want to remove the tub.

Alternatively, can I replace with a toe stopper style drain stopper?  For now, it's a $5 rubber stopper...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the situation? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Have you tried a shop vac to see if you can suck it back up the drain.

Answer (score 1):

These are cheap and a great addition to your toolbox.

Provided it’s long enough, this should get a grip on it.

[image]
.

Answer (score 0):

For $30, you can get a "camera on a stalk" (I have one from DEPSTECH that occasionally works) that will allow you to peer down into there. Many also come with magnets and little hooks to help retrieve lost pieces.